# How to get the container type of an object in R?

Tags: r

Suppose I have an object called v, how do I find out its container type (a vector, a list, a matrix, etc.), without trying each of the is.vector(v), is.list(v) ... ?

Comment: `mode()` provides some insight into this, though it will not differentiate AFAIK between `data.frame()` and `list()` or `vector()` and `matrix()`. A `data.frame()` IS a special type of `list()` and a `matrix()` is simply a `vector()` with some `dim` attributes. Depending on what you need to do, you could always check out some source code to see how other authors have addressed this issue.

Comment: Thank you! So would it be correct to say that matrix is a child class of vector, and data.frame is a child class of list? And so that casting types like as.matrix(i.am.a.vector) has negligible cost?

Comment: @acai - I'll defer to others for the proper hierarchy of object classes, but what typed seems mostly reasonable. In my experience, coercing items via `as.matrix()` and friends is in fact pretty negligible in the grand scheme of things...i.e. whenever I've had a function that was long enough to worry about `system.time()` and `Rprof()`, `as.matrix()` et al was taking up a small part of the time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are three functions which will be helpful for you: `mode`, `str` and `class`

First, let's make some data:

```
nlist <- list(a=c(1,2,3), b=c("a", "b", "c"), c=matrix(rnorm(10),5))
ndata.frame <- data.frame(a=c("a", "b", "c"), b=1:3)
ncharvec <- c("a", "b", "c")
nnumvec <- c(1, 2, 3)
nintvec <- 1:3
```

So let's use the functions I mentioned above:

```
mode(nlist)
[1] "list"

str(nlist)
List of 3
 $ a: num [1:3] 1 2 3
 $ b: chr [1:3] "a" "b" "c"
 $ c: num [1:5, 1:2] -0.9469 -0.0602 -0.3601 0.9594 -0.4348 ...

class(nlist)
[1] "list"
```

Now for the data frame:

```
mode(ndata.frame)
[1] "list"
```

This may surprise, you but data frames are simply a list with a data.frame class attribute.

```
str(ndata.frame)
'data.frame':   3 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ a: Factor w/ 3 levels "a","b","c": 1 2 3
 $ b: int  1 2 3
class(ndata.frame)
[1] "data.frame"
```

Note that there are different modes of vectors:

```
mode(ncharlist)
[1] "character"
mode(nnumvec)
[1] "numeric"
mode(nintvec)
[1] "numeric"
```

Also see that although `nnumvec` and `nintvec` appear identical, they are quite different:

```
str(nnumvec)
 num [1:3] 1 2 3
str(nintvec)
 int [1:3] 1 2 3

class(nnumvec)
[1] "numeric"
class(nintvec)
[1] "integer"
```

Depending on which of these you want should determine what function you use. `str` is a generally good function to look at variables whereas the other two are more useful in functions.